# MSCRM QueryExpression returning null in UnitTest

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to return the first entity that has a value within a value. The only way I can test it is via Unit Testing and they fail every time because its returning null. Not an empty EntityCollection but null. What am I doing wrong here. I just can't see it? ec = null and throws an error when trying to get FirstOrDefault

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
{
    EntityName = "myentity",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
    Criteria = new FilterExpression
    {
        FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
        Conditions = 
        {
            new ConditionExpression("myattribute", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" +somevalue+ "%")
        }
    }
};

EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
return ec.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the Unit Test had a Stub of IOrganizationService which was just returning null for the method.